# syntax error, unexpected kRETURN

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

My code is producing an `unexpected kRETURN` error. I think it's a HAML issue but I don't know why or how to fix it:

```
SyntaxError in MeasurementsController#index 
D:/myAppName/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected kRETURN
```

#### app/helpers/application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def flash_helper
    return if flash.blank?
    out = ""
    flash.each do |key, msg|
      out += "<div class='flash #{key}'>#{msg}</div>"
    end
    raw out
  end  

  def comment
    # do nothing (ruby functions will always take a block)
  end

  def assets_server
    case Rails.env
    when /production|_prod|prd/i
      "assets"
    when /tqa/i
      "assets-tqa"
    else
      "assets-dev"
    end
  end

end
```

I have these gems installed:

- haml (3.1.2, 3.0.25)
- haml-rails (0.3.4)
- rails (3.2.6, 3.2.3, 3.1.0, 3.0.7, 3.0.1)

Comment: Line one of the code you posted doesn't contain a `return` token, and the only `return` token in this file is perfectly valid. The error is likely external to this file. You say you think it's related to HAML, yet you haven't included any of your HAML code?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure about this being an HAML error, but all related errors I have found on the web are about HAML.